# Parameter name: validFrom out of range exception while using ADFS Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have a simple MVC .NET 4.5 application and using an external web page to login to
the server using ADFS.

I configured the application's web.config properly and everything worked fine while login in
to the application via the ADFS and redirecting back to the application having all the user's info.

Recently, I got this error after pressing login from the exteral web page:

```
   [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: validFrom]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken..ctor(IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, UniqueId contextId, String context, String endpointId, Nullable`1 validFrom, Nullable`1 validTo, SymmetricSecurityKey key) +1038
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.CreateSessionSecurityToken(IClaimsPrincipal principal, String context, String endpointId, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo) +276
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(IClaimsPrincipal principal, String context, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo, Boolean isPersistent) +144
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request) +559
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +256
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Why do I get this error?
In the web.config I have no `validFrom` variable neither in the controllers methods.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the exception occurs because ValidFrom >= ValidTo; see line 262 of the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/Tokens/SessionSecurityToken.cs). But that still doesn't explain what is wrong with your configuration.

One possible explanation is that your security token lifetime is too short. A while ago I did some tests involving token expiration. To avoid having to wait for 30 minutes on every test session, I reduced the token lifetime to 1 minute:

```
<securityTokenHandlers>
  <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089">
    <sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:01:00"></sessionTokenRequirement>
  </add>
</securityTokenHandlers>
```

Everything worked fine. But when I came back to the same test environment weeks later, I got the same error as described by OP. My guess is, clock skew between two machines slowly creeped up until it finally exceeded 60 seconds. From then on, tokens were being issued with a ValidTo that had already been surpassed by ValidFrom.

Again, I'm just guessing here. But I do know that once I restored the original token lifetime of 30 minutes, everything was fine again.

```
<sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:30:00"></sessionTokenRequirement>
```

---

Assuming clock skew *is* a potential cause of the error, I would most certainly check the time zone settings of *all* (virtual) machines involved. Imagine two clocks, both showing 10am, but configured with different time zones... even 30 minutes of lifetime could not bridge that gap!